# Large cardinals and in intellectu existence?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, fallacies, descartes

I have had some success in the philosophy of mathematics. Briefly I compare Cantor's sets to the clear and distinct ideas of Descartes which is regarded as philosophically rigorous work; on the other hand large cardinals are from the "in intellectu" existence from the middle ages; this work has been shown to be fallacious. Just because we have definitions for large cardinals doesn't make it so that we have a referrant. What do you think?

Comment: When you say "*Just because we have definitions for large cardinals doesn't make it so that we have a referrant.*" are you asking about philosophical objections to the [Reflection Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle).  Also note that you may need to rephrase your question since "What do you think?" and "am I right" questions are off-topic.

Comment: @NWR Oh no, I guess it does need to be rephrased.

Comment: Indeed, a definition of large cardinal does not have to be consistent with the axioms of set theory, which is a minimum required for mathematical "existence". [Reinhardt cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhardt_cardinal) turned out to be inconsistent, for example.

Comment: No one arrives at a true logical paradox like Russell's paradox applying many versions of [large cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_large_cardinal_properties) including Reinhardt cardinal which only contradicts AC, not ZF. It certainly feels beyond any of our worldly experience, but same goes for real numbers as between every pair of rationals there's an irrational and between every pair of irrationals there's a rational and yet there're much more irrationals than rationals!

Comment: Currently there're mainly 3 sensible principles (Godel's axiom of ordinals, reflection principle, cofinality) support the existence of large cardinals. If you want to criticize the possible existence of large cardinals, then you need to dig in deeper to criticize all 3 above principles/additional axioms outside classic ZF set theories. But due to the indefinite extensibility of set formation, it's very challenging...

Comment: Nihil in intellectu nisi prius in sensu, (Leibniz) nisi intellectus ipse.

Comment: I think we should be conservative and exclude large cardinals, even if it takes adding an axiom.